# Calling App Expose In Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, apple-expose

Is there any way to call App Expose in Lion programmatically, for example on an event tap, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using a **TOTALLY UNDOCUMENTED** API, which might change at any point without notice:

```
void CoreDockSendNotification(CFStringRef, void *);
(...)
CoreDockSendNotification(@"com.apple.expose.front.awake", NULL);
```

Other known arguments are `@"com.apple.expose.awake"` and `@"com.apple.dashboard.awake"`, which activate Mission Control and Dashboard, respectively. `@"com.apple.showdesktop.awake"` used to activate Show Desktop, but no longer works on current versions of macOS.

Note that most applications should not use these calls -- these actions are intended to be invoked directly by the user.

Answer (score 3):

Expose does not exist in Lion, it has been merged with Spaces into the Mission Control application.
You can launch Mission Control:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Mission Control"];
```

Comment: Actually within Mission Control lies App Expose (four finger swipe down), that's what I'm trying to access. Know of any way of accessing that?