# Programmatically show the desktop?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows, pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will show the desktop. How to implement that in for OS X?

Comment: OSX has Exposé that is triggered by F11 .. however I don't think that there is an API for it.

Comment: The user can change those shortcuts, so that method is unreliable.

Comment: why the downvotes? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide all other applications than the sender.

```
-[NSWorkspace hideOtherApplications]
```

Link to documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-hideOtherApplications

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programatically trigger Exposé here is a blog that seems to go down the only usable path: [Triggering Dashboard, Exposé and Spaces](http://meeu.me/blog/dashboard-expose-spaces)  Here is a SO question that goes down this path: [calling-app-expose-in-lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351787/calling-app-expose-in-lion)

Another solution is this SO question: [expose-effect-in-a-mac-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227155/expose-effect-in-a-mac-application) which may be a better way of doing things